# Difference between #table and #list of #records in PowerQuery

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

What are the differences between an item of type `#table` and a list of type `#record` in powerQuery? For example:

```
data = {
    [id=1, name="tom"],
    [id=2, name="sarah]
}
```

And:

```
data = #table(
    {"id", "name"},
    {
      {1, "tom"},
      {2, "sarah"}
    },
)
```

Are they two ways to write the same thing, or should one be used over the other in certain cases?

Comment: These [series](https://ssbi-blog.de/lists-records-and-tables-in-power-query-how-when-and-why/) have good explanations on the topics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is table *may* require strict data types, and only includes records, while list of records can also include values of other types, such as numbers or characters.

Your example can have column types defined in advance:

```
data = #table(
    type table [id=Int64.Type, name=Text.Type],
    {
      {1, "tom"},
      {2, "sarah"}
    },
)
```

As opposite to a list:

```
data = {
    [id=1, name="tom"],
    [id=2, name="sarah"],
    1,
    "a"
}
```